# Is there a way to select a device when running a python script on Google Colab?

Tags: python, google-colaboratory, training-data, huggingface-transformers, huggingface-datasets

I am attempting to run run_language_modeling.py which is a [python script from hugging face](https://github.com/huggingface/transformers/blob/master/examples/legacy/run_language_modeling.py). However, when I try to run it, I've noticed I'm solely using my CPU instead of the GPU (even though the environment is set to use this. So I'm looking for a way to tell the script to use the GPU.

Here's what I have...

To verify that I am using a GPU: `!nvidia-smi`

This shows:

```
Fri Feb 25 11:55:13 2022       
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| NVIDIA-SMI 460.32.03    Driver Version: 460.32.03    CUDA Version: 11.2     |
|-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
| GPU  Name        Persistence-M| Bus-Id        Disp.A | Volatile Uncorr. ECC |
| Fan  Temp  Perf  Pwr:Usage/Cap|         Memory-Usage | GPU-Util  Compute M. |
|                               |                      |               MIG M. |
|===============================+======================+======================|
|   0  Tesla K80           Off  | 00000000:00:04.0 Off |                    0 |
| N/A   32C    P8    26W / 149W |      0MiB / 11441MiB |      0%      Default |
|                               |                      |                  N/A |
+-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
                                                                               
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Processes:                                                                  |
|  GPU   GI   CI        PID   Type   Process name                  GPU Memory |
|        ID   ID                                                   Usage      |
|=============================================================================|
|  No running processes found                                                 |
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

Then, I'm running the following script which calls the `.py` file:

```
!python ./run_language_modeling.py \
    --output_dir=output \
    --model_type=bert \
    --do_train \
    --train_data_file=train.txt \
    --do_eval \
    --eval_data_file=test.txt \
    --per_gpu_train_batch_size 8 \
    --per_gpu_eval_batch_size 4 \
    --num_train_epochs 20 \
    --output_dir ./ \
    --save_steps 1000 \
    --save_total_limit 2 \
    --mlm \
    --overwrite_output_dir \
    --block_size 128 \
    --line_by_line \
    --tokenizer_name bert-base-uncased
```

This continues until the CPU usage goes up to 100%. I assume there might be something like `--device` but I haven't been able to found it. Some other posts I've seen online mention I can do:

```
import os
os.environ["CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES"]="1"
tf_device='/gpu:0'
```

To select the GPU I want, but it's not really doing anything that I can tell. I also tried doing:

```
%%shell

export CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES=0
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import torch

device = torch.device("cpu")

if torch.cuda.is_available():
   print("Training on GPU")
   device = torch.device("cuda:0")
```

Comment: Please don't post only code as answer, but also provide an explanation what your code does and how it solves the problem of the question. Answers with an explanation are usually more helpful and of better quality, and are more likely to attract upvotes.